# No Unicode Mapping Warning while trying to read PDF using pdfcompare Java library

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdfcompare

I am using pdfcompare Java library to compare PDFs.

https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare

While reading a PDF, I'm getting the "No Unicode mapping..." warning. I want to ask if it's ok to ignore this, or there is a problem? What can I do to solve this?

[no unicode mapping warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzaj4.png)

I tried researching on this, but wasn't able to find any solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I've never used pdfcompare; the message means that text extraction won't work. So it's not relevant for rendering.

Comment: Alright thank you.